"Missing sudo password" when trying to 'become_user' as a user that has no password and is configured 'ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'
I am trying to use the options 'become; and 'become_user' in a playbook where the user in question has passwordless sudo on the target machine. But every time I try and run the playbook I get the error "Missing sudo password".
The host is logged in as 'bob'. This account is also the primary user on the target Ubuntu server. (The account created when you install.) There is a second account called 'ansible' that I am trying to become.
The 'ansible' user is in the included '/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users' file as:
ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

It also has no password in '/erc/shadow' (ansible:!:19983:0:99999:7:::). Using SSH keys if I actually have to log in as the user.
playbook is:
- hosts: nas
  become: true
  become_user: ansible
  roles:

But whenever I run the playbook I get:
fatal: [XXX]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}

Specifying all the methods for adding a password (-K and the like) and leaving it blank does not work.
I just want to be able to run the following without entering any more passwords other than adding my SSH keys to the ssh-agent.
 ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml --limit nas


Doesn't sudo require the password of the user invoking it? It requires bob's password, not andible's. Have you tried that? Alternately, is it possible to use su which depends on the password of the account you're changing to, rather than the one you're changing from?


The host is logged in as 'bob' ... a second account called 'ansible' that I am trying to become.

This sudo entry ...
ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

... confers "super powers" to the ansible account, not the bob account.
Re-read the man pages on the sudoers file format.
You need something more like this:
bob ALL=(ansible) NOPASSWD:ALL

That should allow bob to run anything as the ansible account.

Now getting the following error:: The destination directory (/etc/default) is not writable by the current user.

See3ms I cannot run : sudo -u ansible rm /etc/default/fart by had either.

sudo -u ansible bash -c 'sudo touch /etc/default/fart' | That works. Now  how to make ansible do it?

Look like ansible is not coded to do  what I want it to do, after spending time looking over longs and verbose outputs.
However, I have found something that will do what I want.
Consider this solved.

Please, accept an answer for everybody to "consider this solved".
